Angular 17.1.0 "ng serve" command sometimes doesn't work
When I serve my angular 17 project it takes a lot of time to run and sometimes it serve but sometimes it doesn't. When it doesn't serve it gives me this error:
Angular build : An unhandled exception occurred: The service is no longer running  

Searched for long, but I couldn't find anything.

Can you try updating node and npm and regenerate the project? This should solve your error.

Hi, Could you share your node and angular version in your project root directory, It could be helpful to solve your issue

Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.
